# Redux ComponentDidMount not firing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having trouble getting the Component to re-render after an action. I understand that I must return a new object in my reducer, so I'm returning an entirely new state, but its still not triggering a `componentDidMount()` or `render()`

My Component:

```
class AppTemplate extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if(!this.props.settings.user){
            this.props.dispatch(userActions.get());
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        console.log(prevProps, this.props);

        //do some stuff

    }


    render() {

        return (
            <SomeComponent/>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { registration, role, settings } = state;
    console.log(role);
    return {
        registration,
        role,
        settings
    };
}

const connectedAppTemplate = connect(mapStateToProps)(AppTemplate);
export { connectedAppTemplate as AppTemplate };
```

My Reducer:

```
export function role(state = { role : null, loading: true }, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_GET_PENDING':
      return {
        role:null,
        loading: true
      }
    case 'USER_GET_FULFILLED':
      const role = action.payload.data.roles[0];
      const newState = {
        role: role,
        loading: false
      }
      console.log(state, newState);
      console.log(state == newState);
      return newState;
    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

The action is getting fulfilled with no problem, and even the mapToState is logging with the new role, but the componentDidMount is never fireing. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Be sure to mark the given answer as accepted if it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` is only called ONCE. Which is when the component finishes loading for the first time. If you're updating the redux store, then you will get calls to the `componentWillReceiveProps` and IF you trigger a render there, you will see `componentDidUpdate` will fire.

EDIT: While the component will render again when new props are received via redux...`componentDidMount` will still only be called once. You are better off using `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidUpdate` for what you're trying to accomplish.

Credit to Dan O in the comments below (that rhymed) for pointing out my error.

Comment: components automatically re-render when they get new props unless you write a `shouldComponentUpdate` function which decides otherwise.

Comment: @DanO you're correct, I should amend my answer. I try to write Pure Components so in my case I'm typically right.

Comment: @DanO done with the edit and credited you for pointing it out. thanks.